# Curl output cookie jar contents to clipboard

Tags: curl, cygwin, cookiejar

I'm using Curl on a site that returns the cookie upon login. In the command line (cygwin) I'd like to output the cookie data to the clipboard.

Typically I would use

```
> /dev/clipboard
```

at the end of the command but that doesn't seem to work for the cookie data. The only way it seems I can output the cookie jar data is by using

```
curl --cookie-jar cookies.txt
```

This puts in a text file which I'd rather not do. Would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a shell that is able to do that, you can do various things:

```
# Use xclip Linux utility
curl -c >(xclip -i) example.com
# Use Windows' /dev/clipboard
curl -c /dev/clipboard example.com
```

Or if you can access /dev/fd or /proc filesystems (not sure for CygWin), you can utilize those

```
curl -c /dev/fd/4 example.com 4>/dev/clipboard
```

But other than using your shell I'm not aware of curl being able to store the cookies anywhere else than in a file.  And I don't think you're looking for script workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

This actually seems to work fine:
`curl --cookie-jar /dev/clipboard www.google.com`